# How can I keep a Java-based pop-up open even when its parent page is closed?

Tags: macos, safari, games, java

I'd like to run the Java client for [Runescape](http://world87.runescape.com/) but want to quit Safari while the Java pop-up is open. How can I do this?

My idea was finding out the URL of the client and running it through the `java` terminal command, but I'm having huge difficulty location the URL. =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The runescape client is running as part of Safari so you can't quit Safari without killing the client. But you can <del>close</del> **hide** the main Safari window (e.g. with <kbd>Cmd-H</kbd>) at least which will keep Safari running and the client open as well.

Comment: I wish, it still closes =/

Comment: Ah yes, the Java applet is linked to the main runescape window so you can't close that on. Hidding would be possible though.

Comment: any chance to isolate the jar file and run it solo? i had no luck with it so far :s

Answer (score 4):

I tried looking a the source, but the website developer has embedded the applet information inside a bunch of JavaScript.  Also, even if you had the jar(s), if the applet requires communication back to the server, it would be a real pain to get it running.

> For future reference, if they hadn't gotten all creative with the applet code, you could have simply run this command line:
>
> ```
> $ appletviewer http://world87.runescape.com/
> ```

What I recommend is to create a dedicated [**Fluid App**](http://fluidapp.com/) for the website.  It's super easy, just point Fluid at the base URL, and it creates a dedicated application wrapped around the website.  The coolest thing is that you can then simply launch your game directly from Applications.

*Fluid is 100% free, and I am not affiliated with them in any way.*

Answer (score 1):

Well, this won't answer the question but will solve your problem: use the [downloadable version of Runespace](http://www.runescape.com/kbase/guid/Downloads_and_Wallpapers#brown_box_downloads).

Then, for the question itself: you couldn't do what you're asking for, since Safari is responsible for the Java plugin. The only way would be to download the applet code and use the command @OverZealous gave.

Comment: The downloadable version has issues running certain graphics modes. Also, I have Fluid, but it avoids the reason i'm looking for the sole executable. I wish to have my mouse's keys to change to a profile specific to rs only when the client is the active window.