# Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin missing on M1 Mac

Tags: macos, java, apple-silicon

I am trying to run a Java Applet but it says it cannot find Java because the directory `Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/...` does not exist.

I have installed multiple Java versions but they only seem to be added under `Library/Java/...`.

How can I run a Java Applet on a modern M1 machine?

Comment: It seems you are running an old version of Java. Could you please provide your current version? (Run `java -version`)

Comment: `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins` is for Java applets running in the browser, not for standalone applications. How did you install Java, what is the value of `JAVA_HOME`?

Comment: Yes exactly, I need it for a Java applet that is running in my browser, not a standalone application. I have versions 17 and 19 installed.

Comment: How are you running the Applet and where does the error message appear? A screenshot of the relevant parts would be nice. Because [since Safari 12 it doesn't suport the Java Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52386126/update-to-safari-12-0-java-plug-in-no-longer-listed) anymore.

Answer (score 1):

[Install](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/334384/how-can-i-install-java-openjdk-8-on-high-sierra-or-newer-macos) [Java 1.8](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/349465/how-can-i-upgrade-from-oracle-jdk-8-to-openjdk-8-using-homebrew-and-be-sure-it-w) which brings [appletviewer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/appletviewer.html), then [run](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30886/how-can-i-keep-a-java-based-pop-up-open-even-when-its-parent-page-is-closed/31604#31604)
[the applet](https://superuser.com/questions/999778/when-firefox-drops-java-applet-support-how-will-i-run-old-java-applets/999815#999815) with it:

```shell
appletviewer "https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/java/applets/jdk/1.4/demo/applets/Clock/example1.html"
appletviewer file:///path/to/htmlWithApplet.html
```